# Android QuickBlox getFile response issue

Tags: android, quickblox

I have developed chat application. To transfer image in chat, we first upload it to content module and then share that id to receiver. In case of  issue ,  we call to getFile in messagelistner. However, putting same code outside that method works fine. Please have look at following code:

---

MyChatController.java

---

```
  private MessageListener messageListener = new MessageListener() {
    @Override
    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
            System.out.println(String.format(">>> Message received (from=%s, to=%s): %s",from, to, message.getBody()));

        if (onMessageReceivedListener != null)
        {
            onMessageReceivedListener.onMessageReceived(message);
        }
     }
   };
```

Implementation of this methods are in ChatActivity

ChatActivity.java

```
private ChatController.OnMessageReceivedListener onMessageReceivedListener = new ChatController.OnMessageReceivedListener()
 {

        public void onMessageReceived(final Message message)
        {
            final String from = message.getFrom().split("-")[0];
            final String messageString = message.getBody();
            Log.v("----msg from----","from ap "+ from+"-----"+friend.getId().toString());
            if(from.equalsIgnoreCase(friend.getId().toString()))
            {   

                if(messageString.startsWith(">>In thread");
                                    URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
                                    Log.v("---CONNECTION url---","In thread---"+url);
                                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                                    urlConnection.connect();                
                                    String fileDir=null;
                                    File file=null;
                                    File ffile;
                                    if(fileType==SELECT_IMAGE)
                                    {
                                        fileDir=SDCardRoot+"/Globr/Images";
                                    }       
                                    ffile=new File(fileDir);
                                    if(!ffile.exists())
                                    {
                                        ffile.mkdirs();
                                    }           
                                    file = new File(fileDir,filename);
                                    Log.v("---folder file name---","image folder fil created---"+filename);
                                    if(!file.exists())
                                    {
                                        file.createNewFile();
                                    }


                                    FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                                    int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
                                    int downloadedSize = 0; 
                                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                                    int bufferLength = 0;
                                    while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 )
                                    {               
                                        fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);                
                                        downloadedSize += bufferLength;               
                                        Log.v("Progress:","downloadedSize:"+downloadedSize+"totalSize:"+ totalSize) ;
                                    }           
                                    fileOutput.close();
                                    Log.v("File:-------","file is : "+file);
                                    if(downloadedSize==totalSize) filepath=file.getAbsolutePath();  
                                }
                                catch (MalformedURLException e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                catch (IOException e)
                                {
                                    filepath=null;
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }.start();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Result result, Object o) {
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Log:

```
04-19 18:02:26.163: I/System.out(25108): >>> Message received (from=110918, to=115738): <file_image 40418

04-19 18:02:26.193: V/--------IMAge--------(25108): --ID 40418--lenth--5---40418

04-19 18:02:26.193: D/QBASDK RestRequest(25108): 

=========================================================

04-19 18:02:26.193: D/QBASDK RestRequest(25108): === REQUEST ==== 09a23d0f-5fa9-4306-94e8-9ebc8c44c9ec ===

04-19 18:02:26.193: D/QBASDK RestRequest(25108): REQUEST

04-19 18:02:26.193: D/QBASDK RestRequest(25108):     GET https://api.quickblox.com/blobs/40418.json

04-19 18:02:26.193: D/QBASDK RestRequest(25108): HEADERS

04-19 18:02:26.193: D/QBASDK RestRequest(25108): QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1

04-19 18:02:26.193: D/QBASDK RestRequest(25108): QB-SDK=Android 0.8.1

04-19 18:02:26.193: D/QBASDK RestRequest(25108): QB-Token=9c0e70b1c1b2a31bb497f6672e72563fa570d492

04-19 18:02:26.193: D/QBASDK RestRequest(25108):PARAMETERS

04-19 18:02:26.193: D/QBASDK RestRequest(25108):INLINE

04-19 18:02:26.193: D/QBASDK RestRequest(25108):GET https://api.quickblox.com/blobs/40418.json

04-19 18:02:37.304: D/SMACK(25108): 06:02:37 PM SENT (1118266312):  

04-19 18:02:43.050: D/GestureDetector(25108): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 5 mFalseSizeCnt:0

04-19 18:03:03.360: D/GestureDetector(25108): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 5 mFalseSizeCnt:0

04-19 18:03:07.304: D/SMACK(25108): 06:03:07 PM SENT (1118266312):
```

We are not able to get response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**onMessageReceived** method may calling on non main thread or something like this

Try to call your code on main thread instead

Comment: Thanks, putting this in **runOnUIthread** is  working as its in activity but while i am requesting same via **service** i could not get response.   Can you please direct how to call **getFile()** and **getUser()** methods in service.